# Python - invalid syntax for multi-line command

Tags: python, syntax

sorry if this is something really basic. I'm trying to get the cool new DeepFake code featured in a recent Two Minute Papers video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUfJOQKdtAk) working and I'm getting a syntax error for one of their lines of code. Minimum working example below:

```
from modules.generator import OcclusionAwareGenerator

def load_checkpoints(config_path, checkpoint_path):

    with open(config_path) as f:
        config = yaml.load(f)

    generator = OcclusionAwareGenerator(**config['model_params']['generator_params'],
                                        **config['model_params']['common_params'])
    generator.cuda()
```

It's giving a syntax error on the comma at the end of the "generator = " line.

```
generator = OcclusionAwareGenerator(**config['model_params']['generator_params'],
                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm used to using python 2 so my first thought was that it was a python 3 thing but honestly I've got no idea. If anyone knows why this is invalid I'm all ears. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I believe the ability to use multiple `**` arguments in a single call was introduced in Python 3.5; see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#specification.

Comment: Sorry - I've edited it. I'm also using Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work with `python3.7`
I installed some other dependencies through the `requirements.txt` file.

```py
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

It also needs `cuda`, which i don't have, so unfortunately couldn't get this to run successfully on my laptop.